# Unable to list user details from aws cognito user pool in java

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have a user pool in aws cognito which has about 100 user details.I want to list down the email of all users through java code.Below is the code-

```
      AWSCognitoIdentityProvider cognitoIdentityProvider = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
            .withRegion(Regions.fromName(REGION))
            .build();
    try {
    ListUsersRequest req=new ListUsersRequest();
        req=req.withUserPoolId(POOL_ID);

    List<String> attributesToGet=new ArrayList<>();
    attributesToGet.add("email");
        ListUsersResult response = cognitoIdentityProvider.listUsers(req);
    System.out.println(response.getUsers());
```

But when I run the code I get the exception as-**com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.AWSCognitoIdentityProviderException: Missing Authentication Token (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MissingAuthenticationTokenException.**
How to solve this or is there any other way to print all the users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working,one needs to add following line of code-

```
    AWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY);
```

Also,one needs to genertae aws access key and secret key for their aws account explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I would verify that the credentials being passed into AWSStaticCredentialsProvider are valid. Otherwise the code looks correct - I have similar looking code in one of my projects that works fine.

FYI - `listUsers` only returns 60 results at a time. You will need to get the `paginationToken` from the response, add that onto a subsequent request and call `listUsers` again in a loop to retrieve all the users

Comment: bwinant,the credentials are correct as other functionalities are working fine.However for validation,signup I needed to set client id instead of pool id.But for listing and updating the user attribute,only pool id setter is available.Also,do we need to add any policy or other configuration in aws account for listing and updating user pool data?

Comment: You don't need clientId only the poolId for performing listUsers. Whatever user/role is invoking it does need ListUsers permission in IAM

Comment: ok,thanks,could you please provide the code of lines needed for providing the permission.

Answer (score 1):

@bwinant I then replaced my code with below and it fixed the issue.

```
for (;;) {
    result = identityUserPoolProviderClient.listUsers(listUsersRequest);
    System.out.println("Iteration:- " + count + " of " +   
        result.getUsers().size() + " for PaginationToken:- " + 
        result.getPaginationToken());
    System.out.println(result.getUsers().size());
    userTypeList.addAll(result.getUsers());
    for (int i = result.getUsers().size(); i > 0; i--) {
        userTypeList.addAll((Collection<? extends UserType>)  result.getUsers());
    }

    paginationToken = result.getPaginationToken();
    if (paginationToken == null) {
        break;
    }
    listUsersRequest.setPaginationToken(paginationToken);

    count++;
}
```